# get velocity and calculate acceleration DJI SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

Hello i want to get the value of Velocity X in real time , and calculate the acceleration X:
i used the following code as below in the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Aircraft) DemoApplication.getProductInstance()).getFlightController().setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(@NonNull FlightControllerState flightControllerState) {


            float vx1 = flightControllerState.getVelocityX();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                //Do something after 100ms
            }, 100);
            float vx2 = flightControllerState.getVelocityX();
            float accelerationVariableX = (10 * vx2) - (10 * vx1);
            TextView acc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acc);
            //String v1 = Float.toString(vx1);
            //String v2 = Float.toString(vx2);

            acc.setText("accX: " + accelerationVariableX + " m/s²" + "/x1   " + vx1 + "/x2  " + vx2); //  acceleration and velocity 


        }
    });


}
```

}

the application crashed when i open it ,
How to Fix Crashed Apps ?

NB : when i removed this line `

```
((Aircraft) DemoApplication.getProductInstance()).getFlightController().setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(@NonNull FlightControllerState flightControllerState) {
```

`
the app work well

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of the variables is null,  either getProductInstance() or getFlightController().

Are you sure the aircraft is connected and the sdk has competed registering and initialize?   These will be null until after the prior completes.

Comment: thank you for your reply,  the aircraft is connected and sdk competed registering , i dont know whats the problem exacly but im sure the problem is here : DemoApplication.getProductInstance()).getFlightController().setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {

Comment: Have you looked at the individual function return values to see what is null?   From the exception you have something null,  that will help figure out the next step.